# Looping over list of lists (nested for-loops) doesnt work as I want it to

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

What I want this to do is loop over the elements in *board*, look for "P", then check if there are 5 "P"'s in a row (downwards, so to speak). See comments in code for further explanation. Still, inRow is giving me output 15.

Hint: the five "P"'s are not ought to be stationary but placed by the player but for this example, I just placed stationary ones.

```
board = [['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']]
# has 10 rows, with 10 elements in each

inRow=0

for y in range(10): # Loops over each row (y-index)
    x=0 # x-index resets each new y-index loop (start on the first element (0) of each row)
    for pos in board[y]: # pos loops over all elements in current row 
        if pos is "P": # checks if pos is "P"
            for i in range(5): # loops over 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
                if board[y+i][x] is "P": # when i=0, board[y+i][x] is ought to be where we find the first "P", then check if the following rows (we add +1 to y for each loop) is also "P"
                    inRow += 1 # Counter to see if we got 5 in a row
            break 
        x+=1

print(inRow)
```

Comment: The author expected `inRow` to be `5` but got `15` instead.

Comment: don't use `is` with strings. `is` tests for identical objects, not equal strings.

Comment: Do you need it to be made in nested loops? If so, a suggestion would be to loop first over the columns and then over the rows.

Comment: @Daniel Okay! So, use == instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you break, you don't end both loops -- only the second one.

Consequently, when your code finds the first `P`, it increments `inRow` until it equals 5, then breaks. Then your code moves on to the second row, to the second `P`, and increments `inRow` until it equals `9` -- `5 + 4 = 9`.

Although you can restructure your code to avoid this issue altogether, you can also wrap the code in a function and simply return instead of breaking:

```
board = [['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']]

def find(board):
    inRow=0
    for y in range(10): 
        x = 0 
        for pos in board[y]: 
            if pos == "P": 
                for i in range(5): 
                    if board[y+i][x] == "P": 
                        inRow += 1 
                return inRow 
            x += 1
    return inRow

print(find(board))
```

Comment: I don't believe this is strictly correct, although it would give the author the correct output for the specific issue they're having. If you place a second set of "P"s just to the right of the first, the output would be `5` and not the expected `10`.

Comment: Although I didn't resolve it using your suggestion (because the way I did it fits better when used in the project as a whole (and not just the tiny example I pasted here)) you helped me understand what was wrong (the "not breaking the first for-loop"-part) so a huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You add to `inRow` even when there aren't `5` "P"s in a row. Think about this:

The first time you hit a "P" in the second row, you count down and you get `5`. The next time you hit a "P" in the outer `for` loop, you count down and you get `4`. Now you've counted `9` "P"s. Continue this and you'll get `5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15` "P"s.

The solution is to use an intermediate counter, and only add that intermediate count to `inRow` if that counter is `5`.

To correctly count it, you can declare a counter right after `for pos in board[y]:`

```
counter = 0
```

Then, instead of `inRow += 1`, you use `counter += 1`.

Finally, right before your break statement, do a check:

```
if counter == 5:
    inRow += counter
```

Comment: This is great for if you were to have more than 5 "P"'s on board, and searched for all 5-in-a-rows. However, I will only have 5 "P"'s at a time (I should've mentioned it, sorry!) therefore the other post gets marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you must set Flag if there are not 5 'P' in row then check if flag is true then increase inRow

```
inRow=0

for y in range(10):
    x=0 
    for pos in board[y]:
        if pos is "P": 
            flag=True

            for i in range(5): 
                if  not board[y+i][x] is "P":
                    flag=False
            if flag:
                inRow+=1
            break 
        x+=1

print(inRow)
```

Comment: This returns `1`. The author expects a `5`.